# Bind RichTextBox Document to Embedded Text File Without Use of Code-Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, richtextbox

I currently have a large license file embedded in my program that I'd like to bind a RichTextBox to. I've tried multiple methods but found no good way to do this without including something in the code-behind. I'd prefer to bind the document in the XAML itself. As an analogue, I currently have an image bound like so:

```
<Image Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="23" Source="Resources\68PVb9k.png" />
```

Is there any way to achieve this with a RichTextBox document? If I attempt to bind the document directly I get an error:

```
"A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Document' property of type 'RichTextBox'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject."
```

So something like:

```
<RichTextBox Name="richTextBox1" Document="{Binding Path=Resources\InternalLicense.txt}" IsEnabled="False"/>
```

Won't work. (I realize the obvious formatting issues there. It's just an example)

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66054/A-Bindable-WPF-RichTextBox

Comment: I take it the source is a FlowDocument?  Do you need to edit?   Have you considered a FlowDocumentScrollViewer?  If it is just text then have you tried a TextBlock?

Comment: When you say "large license file" do you mean a body of license agreement text, or something else?

Comment: @RobPerkins It's just a .txt file that doesn't really need to be edited.

Comment: Then just use a TextBlock.

Comment: @Blam Needs to still be selectable. Just can't be editable.

Comment: Just ended up using a multiline textbox instead.

Comment: TextBox isReadonly = true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextBox IsReadOnly = true

[TextBoxBase.IsReadOnly Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.isreadonly.aspx)

Comment: I know that. This doesn't really answer the question I had. Highcore's comment is probably the best answer I've gotten so far.

Comment: But it is the solution you used?